# Parsing large XML data

Tags: php, python, xml, perl

I am trying to parse xml files to store data into database. I have written a code with PHP (as below) and I could successfully run the code.

But the problem is, it requires around 8 mins to read a complete file (which is around 30 MB), and I have to parse around 100 files in each hour.

So, obviously my current code is of no use to me. Can anybody advise for a better solution? Or should I switch to other coding language?

What I get from net is, I can do it with Perl/Python or something called XSLT (which I am not so sure about, frankly).

```
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open($file);  
while ($xml->name === 'node1'){
    $node = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->readOuterXML());
    foreach($node->node2 as $node2){
        //READ
    }
    $xml->next('node1');
}
$xml->close();
```

Comment: If you wanted to use perl, I'd recommend the following modules: [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) or [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML).  However, I suspect your problem is really too broad as currently defined to be answered via SO.

Comment: If you know anything about Python you could easily use the [ETree module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse through the XML and then write the results out into a CSV (you can, but don't have to use the [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) depending on what you want to do with the data. - I recently parsed the WURFL XML database (24 mb) using Python and it was done in a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of my script I used to parse the WURFL XML database [found here](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/).

I used the ElementTree module for Python and wrote out a JavaScript Array - although you can easily modify my script to write a CSV of the same (Just change the final 3 lines).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('C:/Users/Me/Documents/wurfl.xml')

root = tree.getroot()

dicto = {} #to store the data

for device in root.iter("device"): #parse out the device objects

    dicto[device.get("id")] = [0, 0, 0, 0] #set up a list to store the needed variables
    for child in device: #iterate through each device

        if child.get("id") == "product_info": #find the product_info id
            for grand in child:

                if grand.get("name") == "model_name": #and the model_name id
                    dicto[device.get("id")][0] = grand.get("value")
                    dicto[device.get("id")][3] +=1

        elif child.get("id") == "display": #and the display id
            for grand in child:

                if grand.get("name") == "physical_screen_height":
                    dicto[device.get("id")][1] = grand.get("value")
                    dicto[device.get("id")][3] +=1

                elif grand.get("name") == "physical_screen_width":
                    dicto[device.get("id")][2] = grand.get("value")
                    dicto[device.get("id")][3] +=1

    if not dicto[device.get("id")][3] == 3: #make sure I had enough 
                                            #otherwise it's an incomplete dataset
        del dicto[device.get("id")]

arrays = []

for key in dicto.keys(): #sort this all into another list

    arrays.append(key)

arrays.sort() #and sort it alphabetically


with open('C:/Users/Me/Documents/wurfl1.js', 'w') as new: #now to write it out

    for item in arrays:

        new.write('{\n    id:"'+item+'",\n    Product_Info:"'+dicto[item][0]+'",\n    Height:"'+dicto[item][1]+'",\n    Width:"'+dicto[item][2]+'"\n},\n')
```

Just counted this as I ran it again - took about 3 seconds.

Comment: Worth noting that this was thrown together in a few minutes as my first attempt to parse an XML file, there are definitely places where I'd clean it up a bit, but I'll leave as is for now. Let me know if it works all right for you!

Answer (score 1):

In Perl you could use [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aTwig), which is designed to process huge XML files (bigger than can fit in memory)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $file= shift @ARGV;

XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { 'node1/node2' => \&read_node })
         ->parsefile( $file);

sub read_node
  { my( $twig, $node2)= @_;
    # your code, the whole node2 string is $node2->sprint

    $twig->purge; # if you want to reduce memory footprint

  }
```

You can find more info about XML::Twig at [xmltwig.org](http://xmltwig.org/xmltwig/)

Answer (score 0):

In case of Python I would recommend using `lxml`.

As you are having performance problems, I would recommend iterating through your XML and processing things part by part, this would save a lot of memory and is likely to be much faster.

I am reading on old server 10 MB XML within 3 seconds, your situation might be different.

About iterating with lxml: http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#tree-iteration

Comment: Did you use PHP? Because it is strange then, may be my xml structure is causing this delay .. coz what I did was just iterated and copy data to a txt file in tab delimited format in each foreach loop .. and yet taking that long .. thanks for sharing your experience.

Answer (score 0):

Review this line of code:

```
$node = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->readOuterXML());
```

Documentation for `readOuterXML` has a comment, that sometime it is attempting to reach out for namespaces etc. Anyway, here I would suspect big performance problem.

Consider using `readInnerXML()` if you could.